# Filtering Debtors from a Transaction Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a challenge allowing only Bookings with Balance show. I was able to filter out debtors based on the below statement but in a case when the person has updated his payment, it gives an error result on the Status field.
please can someone help with a statement to just allow only those with my field statement to return result.
below is the SQL statement of the query

```
SELECT "Print" AS Print, "Make Payment" AS MakePayment, tblBookingPayments.BookingPaymentID, tblBookings.GuestID_FK, tblBookingPayments.Discount, 
CCur(DSum("[Amount]","qryCostsPaymentsUnion","[BookingID]=" & [BookingID] & " AND [Item]<>'" & "Payment" & "'")-([Discount])) AS TotalCost, 
CCur(DSum("[Amount]","qryCostsPaymentsUnion","[BookingID]=" & [BookingID] & " AND [Item]='" & "Payment" & "'")) AS TotalPaid, 
CCur(DLookUp("[Balance]","qryBookingPayments","[BookingID]=" & [BookingID] & " AND [TotalPaid]<>" & [TotalCost])) AS Status, 
tblBookings.BookingID, tblBookingPayments.EmployeeID, tblBookingDetails.CheckInDate, tblBookingDetails.CheckOutDate
FROM (tblBookings INNER JOIN tblBookingDetails ON tblBookings.BookingID = tblBookingDetails.BookingID_FK) INNER JOIN tblBookingPayments ON tblBookings.BookingID = tblBookingPayments.BookingID_FK
ORDER BY tblBookings.BookingID, tblBookingDetails.CheckOutDate;
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Conversion functions such as CCur() will error on Null. DLookup() returns Null if there is no match. Why is CCur needed? Either don't do conversion in query or handle possible null with Nz().

Answer (score 0):

Conversion functions such as CCur() will error on Null. DLookup() returns Null if there is no match. Handle possible null with Nz()

```
CCur(Nz(DLookUp("[Balance]","qryBookingPayments","[BookingID]=" & [BookingID] & " AND [TotalPaid]<>" & [TotalCost]),0)) AS Status,
```

Then include filter criteria under that calculated field: `<>0`.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was able to remove error but I am left with task of filtering only debtors and duplicate BookingID. on inserting filter <>0  in the criteria,  requests for TotalCost, TotalPaid and then gives syntax error and after that says the operation might be too complex.

Comment: It works with my db. I don't see anything in posted query that would prevent `<>0`. You will have to provide revised query for analysis and further explain what issue is with "duplicate BookingID". Edit your question. Provide sample data as text tables.

Comment: Here is the link below to the full Access database so you can review ...https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eyqHFP7g7_DAEEmLH_NPEe3T2gx5gWgu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You should probably go to a forum that has facility for attaching and downloading files.